# Can't login to my XFCE environment from lxdm

Tags: 12.04, xfce, lxdm

I installed `lxdm` as my display manager because I heard its very lightweight. Now after installing it when I select my `Desktop` as `Xfce session` I am not able to login. Basically what happens is it waits for sometime and than reload the same login page.

On the other hand if I select `lxde` as my `Desktop` I am able to login.

So, what am I doing wrong here.

The other problem I am facing with `lxdm` is it doesn't show my default `user account`. I have to select `more` and enter `both` my `username and password` to `login` into any session.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I found a helpful solution at the end of [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871456&highlight=lxdm&page=2) thread.

Essentially,

1. Open `/usr/share/xsessions`
2. Open the `xfce.desktop` file with a text editor
3. Find the name value and replace the space with a dash or hyphen
4. Restart!

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

### date: 2021-06
-- seems there is a bug in the process:
some passwords actually do not work with lxdm login
(e.g. if a dot or comma is contained.)

try to set a different user password, as root:
passwd username